# Hiding all li items except one

Tags: jquery

How could i hide all li items except one??
I would like to hide all element s of li excepting a particular li item

Will this work??

```
        $(".divmenu").find('li').css("display", "none");
        $(".divmenu").find('li nth-child(4)').css("color", "red");
```

Or like this??

```
       $(".divmenu").find('li:not(nth-child(4))').css("display", "none");
```

This one seems simple but it is not working ..Might be wrong syntax?? Please anybody provide simple and efficient techniques

Comment: Except one? Which one? Does it care or not?

Comment: "*Will this work?*" - here's an idea: try it, and then ask us a question if it doesn't.

Comment: You're missing a : in your selector, should be :nth-child(4). See documentation here http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".divmenu").not(":nth-child(4)").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: I found a better way to do this using `$(".divmenu li").not(":eq(3)").hide();`
Note that `:eq()` selector indexes start with zero (0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".divmenu").find('li').not(':nth-child(4)').css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,will work

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {


$(".divmenu li").not('li:nth-child(2)').hide();  

}); 
</script>
```